# Flutter Text only break lines at whitespaces

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-text

My issue is that flutter breaks Text at non whitespace characters:

[image]

How can I tell flutter not to beak text at the "/" but only when it encounters a whitespace?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            width: 220.0,
            child: Text(
              'This should not break here x/y/z',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have been looking into packages like auto_size_text, but found nothing addressing this problem.

### Edit:

Working with '\n' is not an option since the length of the text varies,but it always includes the three x/y/z characters divided by slashes at the end.

I would rather not calculate the size of the rendered text in advance to determine whether a newline should be included before x/y/z. That would seem a little heavy, since these are card titles contained in a ListView.

On the web there is no issue, there the text is only broken at whitespaces:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <div style="background-color: grey; height: 200px; width: 400px;">
        <p style="font-size: 24.0pt;">
            This should not break here x/y/z
        </p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/61081#issuecomment-1103330522

> 1. Replace space with NO-BREAK SPACE `'\u00a0'` where you don't want to break. This forces two characters around it to stay put together in
>    the same line.
> 2. Insert ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE `'\ufeff'` between the characters you don't want to break. Same as the above but takes no space.
> 3. Optionally insert ZERO WIDTH SPACE `'\u200b'` where you want to break. This allows two characters around it to break freely.

To break only around spaces, replace

```dart
Text(string)
```

with

```dart
Text(string.split('').join('\ufeff').replaceAll('\ufeff \ufeff', ' '))
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `TextAlign.justify` to fit the text, and to my liking, you can try:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            width: 220.0,
            child: Text(
              'This should not break here x/y/z',
              textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also `TextAlign.center` not bad.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately that does not solve the problem shown in the picture. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: use '\n' in your text, like this 'This should not break here \n x/y/z',  In this case, x/y/z  is placed on a new line

Comment: That would not work either, since the size of the string varies from Card to Card. I added this to my question. But thank you for the idea!